# Is there some good mailing list for `Computational Science`?

Tags: parallel-computing, reference-request

I am wondering whether there is some very good **mailing list** or **google groups** for Computational Science, where we can discuss questions instead of only asking and replying questions.

In fact, I am more interested parallel computing and numerical solutions of PDEs. But I don't know what and how people in this area are doing. I can only read their papers to grasp the road-map of this area.

Please give me some guiding information. Thanks.

Comment: Are usenet news groups out of the question? something like `sci.math.num-analysis`. I also see many pde questions asked on `comp.soft-sys.matlab` (but for those using Matlab for implementation). I'd be interested in such a mailing list also, but I do not think it exist. googling around, I see this also https://lists.phys.ethz.ch/listinfo/comp-phys-general (computational physics mailing list) I do not know if it is still active or not.

Comment: @Nasser Unfortunately most mailinglists died or are slowly dying as the internet embraces the newer social network model of Q&A or discussion like StackOverflow or Quora. I used to join several mailinglist back in China, but they are all pretty much dead now.

Comment: @Nasser Your [website](http://12000.org) is well edited. And thanks for your comment.

Comment: irc://chat.freenode.net/##computerscience, irc://chat.freenode.net/hpc come to mind

Comment: @Cao Wish I could get the help at these mediums >_> I tried asking around about Chebyshev interpolation at freenode and ##math appears to be school level. But I appear to get quite a bit of help about Fortran at their Fortran channel...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend ResearchGate's computational science topic for general discussion about computational science.

> https://www.researchgate.net/topic/computational_science/